# Zuul Server run application

Tags: java, netflix-zuul

I'm prompted with an error that it can't be connected when I'm starting the server. I'm wondering why it's trying to look for `192.168.100.16` rather than using `localhost`.

I tried running the application using the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack = true`, but this didn't work either.

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 9090

# remove that settings in production
management.security.enabled: false

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/

zuul:
  #Service will be mapped under the /api URI
  prefix: /api
#  Uncomment to disable auto-registering all services read from Eureka
#  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    test:
      path: /redirect/**
      url: http://google.com
    customer-by-address:
      path: /customer-by-address/**
      url: http://localhost:9098
    customer-by-service:
      path: /customer-by-service/**
      serviceId: CUSTOMER-SERVICE
    static:
      path: /static/**

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-server
```

**netstat -tulpn**

```
lesharb@LeshaRB ~ $ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44907         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1969/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1969/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49841           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1969/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43927           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1969/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46137         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1969/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1969/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::44811                :::*                    LISTEN      2210/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::36911                :::*                    LISTEN      3671/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::46165                :::*                    LISTEN      3671/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::41591                :::*                    LISTEN      3671/java       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::65336                :::*                    LISTEN      2210/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      3671/java       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38293           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 192.168.100.12:123      0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50096           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 fe80::3468:6113:b62:123 :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::44987                :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
```

I have such error

```
2017-09-05 10:49:35.310  WARN 3671 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-09-05 10:49:35.310  WARN 3671 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ZUUL-SERVER/192.168.100.12:zuul-server:9090 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zuul is attempting to communicate with Eureka to get a list of services to use when routing requests. However, your netstat output does not show any process listening on port 8761, which is where your configuration says Eureka should be.

Answer (score 1):

As Faron said, your Zuul instance is trying to connect to a eureka server. 
You can either remove this from your application.yml

```
 eureka:
   client:
     serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
```

or start eureka (especially since you have some routes with a `serviceId`)

If you want to have a example of zuul with eureka, this is a good resource. [Creating microservice using Spring Cloud, Eureka and Zuul](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/02/05/part-1-creating-microservice-using-spring-cloud-eureka-and-zuul/)